# Detect static data changes and apply them in template, without restarting server in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am beginner who is building a template using *node.js*.

I would like my static data to be in an external file (`.json`) from a different location.

When any changes made in static data, will *node.js* reflect the changes in the template without restarting the node server?

Any input will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That depends on how / when you read it.

Comment: Hi @Slaks, Currently, I am doing a post request to my node server with json data. When I post data, all the changes within the server are reflected by using nodemon but not the files from a different location which are not in the server. Is there a way to detect the changes to the files which are not in the server?

Comment: Different location === another server?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener

Comment: @Dez Different location === different directory

Comment: Use `fs.watch` as @SLaks recommends checking datetime of the file plus maybe checksum of the file contents.